# AVD's HAXM, AEHD and Hyper-V loop of death... haxm is not installed failure

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, hyper-v, haxm

I need help making emulator working on a new clean Windows 10 install. I'm stuck on a **HAXM, AEHD, Hyper-V, AVD** loop of death. I'm installing `Android Studio` on a decent and modern machine with core i5 4430, 4th generation.

Intel Virtualization is enabled on Bios. As you know `HAXM` is deprecated since emulator v33, so I'm not installing it. Instead I installed `AEHD` as the docs says and `Hyper-V` is already disabled in all his names.

The issue is that when trying to start the emulator, it displays this error: "**intel haxm is required to run this avd haxm is not installed**". And if I try to install a new AVD, when selecting system image, it says the same:  "**HAXM IS NOT INSTALLED**" in red.

So I'm stuck and can't use AVD... help please. I'm using the last version of Android Studio and sdk tools, emulator, etc...

Comment: Have you read https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows? Also what output do you get on the command `sc query aehd`?

Comment: @Robert nothing appears on screen...

Comment: That is a command-line command that needs to be executed in a CMS.exe shell or a PowerShell.

Comment: @Robert or in the terminal inside AS, and I'm executing it there

Comment: Seems like PowerShell in powershell (the terminal inside AS is a powershell terminal) you have to use the full executable name to get an output thus the correct command is `sc.exe query aehd`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't ask me why, but the error dissapeared doing exactly what google is telling you not to do.

If you install Hyper-V and Hypervisor platform, suddenly the error dissapeared.